# connecting to Unix server using putty and running few unix commands using c#

Tags: c#, putty

I need to connect to unix server using putty.exe and to run the 'sudo' command into it.
Here server, username, paswd and sudo commands are dynamic in nature. we will be passsing them  during execution or can be put in an test.xls file and can read thru the file.
Your early response is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using C# to control Putty you should consider using an SSH library, like [SSH.net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/).  That will allow you to connect to the SSH service on your Unix server.